# Deploy Angular 6 + ASP.NET Core SPA with Release Definition on TFS-VSTS-Azure DevOps

Tags: angular, tfs, .net-core, release, continuous-deployment

at the moment I have the Build Pipeline configured as it follows:
[image: Build Pipeline]

Pipeline works, tests run and so on but when I have to deploy the web application, I am forced to do it manually:

1. Publish the backend using Visual Studio Publish feature
   [image: Publish VS]
2. Build frontend using ng build passing a configuration environment like --dev
   [image]
3. Copy "dist" folder content in wwwroot folder
4. Zip the whole publish folder to the environment server machine (dev, test etc), SQL scripts included.

I'm sure that it's possible to automatize the whole process and I saw that from the Build pipeline, clicking on Release from the Build Pipeline 
[image: Release Pipeline]

but I feel kinda stuck on it.
One problem is that there is not a task ad hoc for Angular.
And I have another doubt whether to make changes (in Build pipeline or Release one) as I saw some guides, like this one where actually some [guy](https://mehraban.com.au/2017/04/27/vsts-cicd-angularcli-aspnetcore/) modified Build pipeline first, to obtain the right package with that and then publish it.

Any ideas?